# How to get whole list of changes for a previously-merged-to-master branch?

Tags: git

I have a working branch WB, that I merged to master using PR.
Then I reverted those changes in master.

Now if I create a new PR (WB to master), I can't see the whole list of changes, just the last changes for the last commit, and the complete list of commits.

How can I see the whole list of changes?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation :

```
     WB got merged here (through PR)
             |  got reverted here (through another PR maybe ?)
             |     |
             v     v
*--*---*-----M--*--R--* <- master
    \       /
     *--*--* <- WB
```

As you can see in  the diagram above, `git` now considers that `WB`, in its current state, *has already been merged* to `master`.

You need to choose one way to create something that will bring back the changes you want :

```
*--*---*-----M--*--R--* <- master
    \       /          \
     *--*--* <- WB      *--* <- newWB (with changes)
```

---

One way to create this `newWB` branch is to "revert the revert" :

- If the revert was done in one single commit :

```
# create a new branch starting off master :
git checkout -b newWB master

# re-revert the 'R' commit :
git revert R
```

- If the revert `R` is the result of a merge request, use [`git revert -m xx`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#Documentation/git-revert.txt--mparent-number) :

```
# create a new branch starting off master :
git checkout -b newWB master

# revert the merge commit :
git revert -m 1 R
```

You can now push that new branch and merge it to `master`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation!